# NodeJS unexpectedly adding undefined in beginning of every FS writeFile

Tags: node.js, for-loop, fs, writefile

Everytime I run my script, **undefined** is in the beginning and I have no idea why. I want to convert this file

```
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
```

into

```
username: user
password: pass
username: user
password: pass
username: user
password: pass
```

but everytime I run it it ends up being..

```
undefinedusername: user
password: pass
username: user
password: pass
username: user
password: pass
```

My NodeJS script is the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync('details.txt', 'utf-8');
var updatedText;

data = data.replace(/:/g, '\n');

lines = data.split("\n");

for (line in lines) {
    if (line % 2 == 0) {
        updatedText += `username: ${lines[line]}\n`
    } else if (line % 2 == 1) {
        updatedText += `password: ${lines[line]}\n`
    }
}

fs.writeFile('converted.txt', updatedText, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
```

All help is of course appreciated! :)

Comment: do you have a way of debugging it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updatedText` has value undefined. When you do updatedText += ..., the first time when it runs, it adds undefined to the value

`var updatedText = ""` will fix the issue

Here is a snippet showing the issue:

```js
var a;
console.log(a+"text1")
var b = ""
console.log(b+"text2")
```